# What is the best place to report bugs in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried https://connect.microsoft.com before. First I was unsure if it is the right place, because you can not tell them, that you have a problem specific to ASP.NET MVC. I guess thats why I can only find 20 entries regarding ASP.NET MVC there.

What is the best place to report bugs / suggestions?

Comment: What bug have you found?

Comment: Actually none :-). But I just realized that I have to duplicate the code of AuthorizeAttribute.cs for some reason and I am not happy about it. You can see the problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886862/how-to-keep-a-parameter-from-url-after-redirect-to-login-aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/) is a project manager for ASP.NET MVC project.  You can go to [his blog](http://haacked.com/) and try to get in [contact with him](http://haacked.com/contact.aspx).  He's usually very good to respond.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the [offical Microsoft ASP.NET MVC forums](http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx).

That can also help determine if the issue is a bug or feature.

Comment: @ downvoter ... at the time of this post (2009) this answer was pretty valid and fair. Be nice!